# How Ant can get a value read from a file into a property value?

Tags: ant, build-process, build, properties

The file looks like:

```
a1,b1
a2,b2
...
```

I know the value "a2".
How to get the value "b2" into a property value.

I know how to select line which contains "a2" by:

```
<linecontains>
  <contains value="a2"/>
</linecontains>
```

But **I do not know** how to set a property value to "b2".
I am at your disposal for more other information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following does the trick for me:

```
<loadfile srcfile="data" property="result">
     <filterchain>
           <linecontains>
                <contains value="a2"/>
           </linecontains>
           <tokenfilter>
                <replacestring from="a2," to=""/>
           </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo message="${result}"/>
```

As you pointed out, first the line the the 'a2' will be selected. The tokenfilter then replaces a2 and the colon with nothing. Hope that helps.